# How to retrieve data with jquery from dynamically created html objects

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dynamic, web

I have a web project which I inject some question with created html code into the html page. Since these html object created dynamically I do not know how many questions will be and what will be their IDs. I need to get the selected answers.

Here there is a piece of html code created dynamically and some javascript functions with JSFiddle demo. nextPage function where I try to get the selected answers do not work.

```
function nextPage() {
var results = new Array();
var contents = $(this).parents("div").parents("div").find("input");
contents.filter(":checked").each(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    results.push($(this).parent().children().get(idx + 1).innerHTML);
    alert($(this).parent().children().get(idx + 1).innerHTML);
});
contents.filter(":text").each(function () {
    results.push($(this).val());
});

alert(results.join(";"));
pageNumber += 1;
window.location = '#question' + pageNumber;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/2/)

How can I get the selected answers? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following (is that what you are looking for):

```
 var pageNumber = 1, isLastPage = 2, results = [];

function nextPage() {

  var contents = $('#question' + pageNumber).find(".answers");    

  contents.filter(":checked").each(function () {        
    var text = $(this).next().find("span.ui-btn-text").text();
     if( text == undefined || text == ""){
         text = $(this).parent().next().text();
     }
    results.push(text);       
  });

   pageNumber += 1;

  if(pageNumber > isLastPage){
     alert("Test Finished, all answers are : " + results.join(";"));
     return;   
  }
   window.location = '#question' + pageNumber;
}

function prevPage() {
   pageNumber -= 1;
   window.location = '#question' + pageNumber;
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/5/

i hope it helps.

Comment: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/frozt/gyztc/1/) here in this example I have extended the types. But I failed to retrieve the slider value selected by the user. Could you pls check the code?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyztc/3/) Thanks for the help. With small extension I could get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the @maverickosama92 solution to a more simpler approach, see if this is what you need.

Working Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/7/

Simpler Approach:

```
var pageNumber = 1, isLastPage = 2, results = [];

function Responses()
{
    var jqResponses = $('body').find(":checked");
    var arrResponses = [];
    jqResponses.each(function(){
        arrResponses.push($('label[for*="' + this.id + '"]').text());
    })

    alert('Responses: ' + arrResponses.join(";"))
}

function nextPage() {

    pageNumber += 1;

    if(pageNumber > isLastPage){
        Responses();    
        return;   
    }
    window.location = '#question' + pageNumber;
}

function prevPage() {
    pageNumber -= 1;
    window.location = '#question' + pageNumber;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a simpler solution. Thanks for the answer. But there will be text or slider inputs as well and in those cases I think it would be better to get answers for each question separately as @maverickosama92 did.

Answer (score 0):

As you didnt create your click event with jquery, your $(this) is not getting the button element, it is getting the window object. Then you pass the window object to jquery.

> The value of *this* within a function when called from the onclick
>   event will be a reference to the global (window) object. ([see link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener))

You can solve it by either adding your click events using jquery and remove the **onclick="nextPage()"** from html. Something similar to this (of course that you should apply it only to the "next buttons"):

```
$('input[type=button]').bind('click',nextPage);
```

Or you can keep using your **onclick="nextPage()"** inside html and you can get the clicked button like this:

```
var $clickedButton = $(this.event.target);
```

So your function will be:

```
function nextPage() {

    var results = new Array();
    var contents = $(this.event.target).parents("div").parents("div").find("input");
    contents.filter(":checked").each(function () {
        var idx = $(this).index();
        results.push($(this).parent().children().get(idx + 1).innerHTML);
        alert($(this).parent().children().get(idx + 1).innerHTML);
    });
    contents.filter(":text").each(function () {
        results.push($(this).val());
    });

    alert(results.join(";"));
    pageNumber += 1;
    window.location = '#question' + pageNumber;
}
```

[NEW JSFiddle updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/14/)

I dont know much about jquery mobile. And I dont know if putting the events on html is the best way to bind you click event but I guess it would be better to bind your click events using jquery.

[JSFiddle binding events with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/15/)

Comment: The problem for me was I insert these questions after document created and had problems binding the events in that case.I couldnt make Next button event fired since these buttons inserted in the middle of process. To solve that problem I created that NextPage function and called it. But I couldnt check your answer. JSfiddle demo was not responding when Next button clicked.

Comment: Sorry, I only tested my answer on chrome. I have updated the JSFiddle, so you can check it. But the best way to do it is to bind it with jquery. Because I know that adding the event parameter in the function inside html will not work in some Android native browsers, since I have tried before. And I guess you are building a web app, right? Check the last JSFiddle in my update. And if you are making an web app remember to bind to touchstart and touchend events as well. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I am trying to build a web app and then make it an ipad native app with phonegap. I am new to javascript so currently learning it by trial and errors. @maverickosama92 solution helped me a lot actually and thank you for the warning. At least I know where to check if it fails in some devices.

Comment: There are a lot of blog posts explain how to make better phonegap apps. There are quite a few tricks to accomplish a good and responsive phonegap app. Good luck. PS.: This is one blog post with a few tricks: [link](http://floatlearning.com/2011/03/developing-better-phonegap-apps/)